# Personal Facebook usage statistics

Tags: facebook, statistics

Is it possible to see personal Facebook usage statistics from facebook.com or some other web service? By statistics, I mean, for example, the total number of likes, posts, logins, etc. (maybe detailed in periods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the best option is Wolfram Alpha.

Check it out at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=facebook%20report

:)

Answer (score 4):

[Klout.com](http://klout.com/) offers, as part of its measurement of how "influential" you are online, some Facebook stats such as # of likes and comments (total / per post).

Disclaimer: Klout is quite limited with regards to Facebook (being more Twitter-oriented), and it seems **a Twitter account is required** to be able to use it at all.

(But at least Klout proves that some such statistics are indeed available through Facebook's APIs, so quite possibly there are other services that provide what you ask for...)

Answer (score 1):

As all of those apps no longer work but here is a new Facebook app: ["Facebook Analytics"](https://www.facebook.com/games/analytics-scholatec/)

It will give you all those answers and more in a very user friendly way. It also works for pages. Here is the description from the page:

> A free tool for analysing your Facebook data. Use Analytics to know:
>
> - The total number of likes, comments and shares
> - Who comments and likes the most
> - Which users get the most likes and comments
> - Who the most influential users are
> - Which content generates the most interest
> - Who are the most influential users outside of your social circle

[image: Most liked users]
[image: Most liked photos]
[image: Most liked posts]